# Counting all occurrences of digits in a string

Tags: ruby, string

You are given a string S. Count the number of occurrences of all the digits in the string S.

Input:
First line contains string S

Output:
Count the number of occurences of 1 in the entered number and print the output.
 I tried to attempt the given problem like this:

```
number=$stdin.gets.chomp
number.split('').map(&:to_i)
number.each do |numbers|
  i==0
  while numbers===1
    i+=1
  end
end

puts i
```

But, it's not executing.
Can someone please suggest how may I do it?

Comment: You first say that you are given a string, but then say count the number of occurrences of 1 in the number. Is it a string or a number?

Comment: counts digits: `s.scan(/\d/).size`

Comment: "not executing" does not say exactly what is wrong.  Is it running but giving the wrong number?  Is it failing with a syntax error?  What input did you try?

Answer (score 5):

A clean way to do what you want in ruby

```
number=$stdin.gets.chomp
number.count('1')
```

Comment: `gets.count('1')`

Answer (score 5):

```
str = "1a2b &32T2*3"
```

You can count the total number of digits in the string like so:

```
str.count('0123456789')
  #=> 6
```

If you wish to count the number of occurrences of each digit in the string, you could use a *counting hash* (see [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new)):

```
str.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 if c =~ /\d/ }
  #=> {"1"=>1, "2"=>3, "3"=>2}
```

or use the method [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
h = str.each_char.group_by(&:itself).select { |k,_| k =~ /\d/ }
  #=> {"1"=>["1"], "2"=>["2", "2", "2"], "3"=>["3", "3"]}
h.update(h) { |*,v| v.count }
  #=> {"1"=>1, "2"=>3, "3"=>2}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged (here all keys). See the doc for details.

Comment: Wow that `update` trick! Ruby is always good for surprising learnings, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There were several problems with your code. First you didn't actually set `numbers` to be an array, you can do that by saying `numbers = numbers.split('').map(&:to_i)`

Then you should declare the `i` variable outside of the loop. Instead of saying `i == 0`, use `i = 0` for the assignment operator

Instead of using a `while` loop, you should use an `if` statement.

This code is assuming your string is only all numbers.

```
numbers = $stdin.gets.chomp
numbers = numbers.split('').map(&:to_i)
i = 0
numbers.each do |number|
  if number === 1
    i += 1
  end
end
```

If your string consists of letters, numbers or special characters, you could do this

```
numbers = $stdin.gets.chomp
numbers.split('').select { |c| c=~ /1/ }.length
```

Comment: You can also use `numbers.chars.select { |c| c=~ /1/ }.size`

Comment: Change `number.split('').map(&:to_i)` to `numbers`